# Google MyMaps doesn't show polygons properly

Tags: qgis, google-maps, google-earth

I have encountered a weird problem. Since I did the map digitizing in QGIS and next exported it to .kml format using MMQGIS plugin I am losing a few shapes in Google MyMaps.

Straight after file export, I opened it on

[image]

Google Earth where everything is fine. Unfortunately, when I exported the same file to Google MyMaps, a few polygons are missing. They have been turned into the polylines only.
I want them to be displayed as polygons with proper color fill, set previously yet in QGIS.
I know, that MMQGIS sometimes doesn't return all colors properly, but this time everything seems to be alright with the plugin, as the .kml file is fully valid in Google Earth.
I have 2 questions then:

1. What should I do to avoid a situation like this? Have I done some mistakes during digitizing?
2. How can I turn the enclosed polyline into the polygon in Google MyMaps?

[image]

Next, when I export the map from Google MyMaps into .kml format and open it in Google Earth, I am getting the same result with lost polygons. I think, that Google MyMaps must have some bug then.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable way to fix it is via code.
We must open our .kml file in i.e. Notepad ++, where next we should:

1. Find our broken polygon (Ctrl+F)
   [image]
2. If you find your broken polygon, you can compare it with the previous or the next one. At first glance, you will spot, that the code is wrong. Firstly, the `<styleUrl>` must be changed from
   #line-000000-3000

to

```
   <styleUrl>#poly-0957FF-3000-116</styleUrl>
```

because we need the polygon instead of line.

1. We must also include the  feature into our code, because it doesn't appear in our broken polygon:
   We have:
   ...

   1

We should have:

```
   <Polygon>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
```

and next, close it at the end
[image]

1. Save the file and re-open in Gooogle Earth. It should be fine

[image]